# Accessing a method using getattr

Tags: python, oop, getattr

When creating a new class instance, I'm trying to call a method in a different class however can't get it to work. Here's what I have:

```
class DataProject(object):    
    def __init__(self, name=none,input_file=None,datamode=None,comments=None,readnow=True):
        ..............
        # here's where I'm trying to call the method in the other class
        if type(input_file) == str:
            self.input_file_format = self.input_file.split(".")[-1]
            if readnow:
                getattr(Analysis(),'read_'+self.input_file_format)(self,input_file)

class Analysis(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass # nothing happens here atm

    def read_xlsx(self,parent,input_file):
        """Method to parse xlsx files and dump them into a DataFrame"""
        xl = pd.ExcelFile(input_file)
        for s in sheet_names:
            parent.data[s]=xl.parse(s)
```

I'm getting a `NameError: global name 'read_xlsx' is not defined` when I run this with afile.xlxs as input which made me think that I just discovered a massive hole in my Python knowledge (not that there aren't many but they tend to be hard to see, sort of like big forests...).

I would have thought that `getattr(Analysis(), ... )` would access the global name space in which it would find the Analysis class and its methods. And in fact `print(globals().keys())` shows that Analysis is part of this:

`['plt', 'mlab', '__builtins__', '__file__', 'pylab', 'DataProject', 'matplotlib', '__package__', 'W32', 'Helpers', 'time', 'pd', 'pyplot', 'np', '__name__', 'dt', 'Analysis', '__doc__']`

What am I missing here?

EDIT:

The full traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\MPython\dataAnalysis\dataAnalysis.py", line 101, in <module>
    a=DataProject(input_file='C:\\MPython\\dataAnalysis\\EnergyAnalysis\\afile.xlxs',readnow=True)
  File "C:\MPython\dataAnalysis\dataAnalysis.py", line 73, in __init__
    getattr(Analysis(),'read_'+self.input_file_format)(self,input_file)
  File "C:\MPython\dataAnalysis\dataAnalysis.py", line 90, in read_xls
    read_xlsx(input_file)
NameError: global name 'read_xlsx' is not defined
```

My main call is:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    a=DataProject(input_file='C:\\MPython\\dataAnalysis\\EnergyAnalysis\\afile.xlx',readnow=True)
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback? There may be something more subtle going on and it might help.

Comment: What is more important post your __main__ but your problem most likely falls that you are calling for a function before it's defined.

Comment: It looks like you have a `read_xls` method that tries to call `read_xlsx`, but forgets to put `self.` in front of the call.

Comment: Take a look at line 90. The problem seems to be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the full traceback, it appears that your `DataProject` class is calling (successfully) the `Analysys.read_xls` method, which in turn is trying to call `read_xlsx`. However, it's calling it as a global function, not as a method.

Probably you just need to replace the code on line 90, turning `read_xlsx(input_file)` into `self.read_xlsx(input_file)`, though you might need to pass an extra parameter for the parent `DataProject` instance too.

Answer (score 2):

`getattr()` works as you describe it in both Python2.x and Python3.x. The bug must be somewhere else.

This modification of your code (none of the core logic is changed) works fine for instance:

```
class DataProject(object):    
    def __init__(self, name="myname",input_file="xlsx",datamode=None,comments=None,readnow=True):
        if type(input_file) == str:
            self.input_file_format = input_file.split(".")[-1]
            if readnow:
                getattr(Analysis(),'read_'+self.input_file_format)(self,input_file)

class Analysis(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass # nothing happens here atm

    def read_xlsx(self,parent,input_file):
        """Method to parse xlsx files and dumpt them into a DataFrame"""
        print("hello")

a=DataProject()
```

Output is:

```
$ python3 testfn.py
hello
```

### Why  using `getattr()` in this way is usually a bad idea

The way you are using `getattr` forces a naming convention on your methods (`read_someformat`). *The naming of your methods should not be a core part of your program's logic*. - You should always be able to change a function's name at every call and definition of that function and leave behaviour of the program intact.

If a file format needs to be handled by a specific method this logic should be delegated to some unit (e.g a function) with responsibility for this. One way (there *are* others) of doing this is to have a function which takes the input and decides which function needs to handle it:

```
def read_file(self,file,format):
    if format == `xls`:
        self.read_xls(file)
    if format == `csv`:
        self.read_csv(file)
```

The above snippet does have its issues too (a better way to do it would be the [chain of responsibility pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) for example) but it will be fine for small scripts and is much nicer.

Comment: Thanks @Mike. Could you explain why you wouldn't recommend using getattr this way? I still thinking whether I got the approach right in general so I'd be interested in your comments :)

Comment: @pandita I've modified my answer to include a section on that. Let me know if you want more detail.

Comment: +1 very good. Now I got from making a silly mistake to learning something new in about 60 minutes :)